# Is it possible to change ClusterId in Hadoop SecondaryNameNode?

Tags: hadoop, hdfs

Is it possible to change ClusterId in Hadoop SecondaryNameNode?
I have a cluster where, due to some mistakes in the initial configuration, NameNode and DataNodes have same configuration about ClusterId and NamespaceId and work correctly, but SecondaryNameNode is using another ClusterId so it cannot perform the checkpointing.

In the log of the SecondaryNameNode I get the following exception:

```
ERROR org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.SecondaryNameNode: Exception in doCheckpoint
java.io.IOException: Inconsistent checkpoint fields.
LV = -60 namespaceID = 895971557 cTime = 0 ; clusterId = CID-c6b1fd29-d147-43a7-883e-e18f9f500112 ; blockpoolId = BP-1598513364-192.168.6.17-1454431796170.
Expecting respectively: -60; 1481475274; 1437642961430; CID-52d1c91c-0dc6-4d7f-8d79-48caaffe484d; BP-417298265-192.168.6.20-1401112956239.
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.CheckpointSignature.validateStorageInfo(CheckpointSignature.java:134)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.SecondaryNameNode.doCheckpoint(SecondaryNameNode.java:535)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.SecondaryNameNode.doWork(SecondaryNameNode.java:398)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.SecondaryNameNode$1.run(SecondaryNameNode.java:363)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.SecurityUtil.doAsLoginUserOrFatal(SecurityUtil.java:412)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.SecondaryNameNode.run(SecondaryNameNode.java:359)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
```

Is there any way to reconfigure the SecondaryNameNode?
I found many explanations about how to change the ClusterId for NameNode and DataNodes but not for SecondaryNode.

Comment: Clear the metadata in secondary namenode and change the cluster id in the file. Then start the secondary namenode.

Comment: Thanks @AmalGJose. Can you please tell me where to find the file with the metadata in the secondary namenode? I know where it is for the namenode and the datanodes (the VERSION file). But how can I find the metadata of the secondary namenode?